# Postgres create table error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create my very first table in `postgres`, but when I execute this SQL:

```
create table public.automated_group_msg (
  automated_group_msg_idx integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval ('automated_group_msg_idx'::regclass),
  group_idx integer NOT NULL,
  template_idx integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT automated_group_msg_pkey PRIMARY KEY (automated_group_msg_idx),
  CONSTRAINT automated_group_msg_group_idx_fkey FOREIGN KEY (group_idx)
  REFERENCES public.groups (group_idx) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT automated_msg_template_idx_fkey FOREIGN KEY (template_idx)
  REFERENCES public.template (template_idx) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: relation "automated_group_msg_idx" does not exist

Comment: Do you just want `automated_group_msg_idx` to be an auto incrementing id?

Comment: Yes. It is auto increment primary key

Answer (score 2):

Your error is (likely) because the sequence you're trying to use doesn't exist yet.

But you can create a sequence on the fly using this syntax:

```
create table public.automated_group_msg (
  id serial primary key,
  ... -- other columns
)
```

---

Not directly related to your question, but naming columns with the table name in the name of the column is generally speaking an anti-pattern, especially for primary keys for which `id` is the industry standard. It also allows for app code refactoring using abstract classes whose id column is always `id`. It's crystal clear what `automated_group_msg.id` means and also crystal clear that `automated_group_msg.automated_group_msg_id` is a train wreck and contains redundant information. Attribute column names like `customer.birth_date` should also not be over-decorated as `customer.customer_birth_date` for the same reasons.

Comment: looking at postgres documentation and seems like nextval should also work like serial. Actually I was looking in the database that I am working with and thats how the schema is defined for some tables, so think syntactically the way i have written should be right.

Comment: @user8895989 No - mostly incorrect. In postgres, auto increment is implemented using a `sequence` object. A table definition that refers to the `nextval` of a sequence requires that the sequence object be already created. Like many SQL inspections of objects, the SQL shown is postgres's internal representation of the SQL, not the SQL originally entered by the DBA/dev. However, there is no advantage whatsoever in doing this manually - just use the convenience syntax of `serial` and everything will be OK. Defining sequences separately gives you no advantage whatsoever, except typing practice.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Also, the naming convention that you suggested makes complete sense, it is a overkill and probably makes things more confusing. Thanks for your amazing feedback.

Comment: Of course the alternative is to create the sequence before creating the table, which is probably what'll you find in a database dump. It would probably also include setting the sequence's current value.

Comment: @jcaron that's exactly what `serial` is converted to before execution: a `create sequence` and a `create table` that references the sequence`. `serial` is just a super convenient short hand for that - it's not really an "alternative", it's an abbreviation.

Comment: @Bohemian, I know, but there may be cases where you want to do it "separately". Cases include sharing a sequence between several tables or columns, or sequences with names different from the auto-generated one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the sequence before creating the table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE automated_group_msg_idx;
```